# updating multiple rows in django database

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have 5 records in the database and want to update all the values of a particular field called "ret_name".
For that, I have written the following code in views:

```
def retap_list(request, date_selected):
    obj = ret_tbl.objects.filter(curr_date = date_selected)
    obj[1].update(ret_name = "change")
    print(obj[1].ret_name)
```

But it is showing me the following AttributeError:
"'ret_tbl' object has no attribute 'update'"

How should I update each row one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) method works on quesrysets not on the instances. So, you need to filter objects first and then:

```
objs = ret_tbl.objects.filter(curr_date=date_selected)
objs.update(ret_name="change")
```

All of the objects in queryset will be updated. If you need to update a particular object maybe it's a good idea to use [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) instead.

Comment: I mean instead of update, e.g `objs[1].ret_name = 'name'` and then `objs[1].save()`.